# Sound design courses and full education programs.

Tags: sound-design, course, recommendations, degree

I live in a not very progressive country, especially with regards to specialisms like sound design. It is in north-eastern europe. And after researching the web I can not find out if there is a place to receive a good education in sound design from a professional perspective.

So my question is: can you recommend the best higher full time education institutions in the field of sound design, within Europe and US?

Comment: Looking at all of the above, I guess the UK is the center for Sound design training! Lucky guys! Does anyone from Spain, France, or Italy, have anything to say about their sound design institutions?
____________ And to those of you who studied at the courses listed above - do these academies help their graduates get a job? Thanks

Comment: yeah thanks =) i hope one day i'll learn this language

Comment: Anyone know of any 'distance learning' programs for learning sound design?

Comment: A lot of academies provide their courses online, for example - PointBlank and Berklee college of Music. I saw about 5-7 distance learning offers on the web only around London...
But the price is too big for that i think and signing to any attending requiring course will be more affordable

Answer (score 5):

In the UK, Ravensbourne run a fantastic course called "Sound Design" - it's a down-to-earth, hands-on, vocational, course: lots of work, and just about enough theory. It's very realistic - you don't get lots of perks and top gear, but you do get access to industry standard stuff, and a tight broadcasting/AV community with a lot of common sense. The tutors know what they're talking about and many of them work on real-life non-academic projects. 
Highly recommended.

Comment: i think this is the best place for me

Answer (score 5):

Savannah College of Art and Design in Savannah Georgia USA also has a sound design program.  I believe their sound program is fairly new so it doesn't have the reputation of a place like USC.
Nevertheless, it might be worth looking into.

[SCAD sound design](http://www.scad.edu/sound-design/index.cfm)

Comment: looks delicious

Answer (score 3):

The [MSc in Sound Design](https://web.archive.org/web/20150117040149/http://sd.caad.ed.ac.uk:80/mscsounddesign/) at [The University of Edinburgh](https://web.archive.org/web/20141230042603/http://www.ed.ac.uk/home) has an excellent reputation.

[image: The University of Edinburgh]

Answer (score 3):

There's also LIPA in the UK, im currently in my 2nd year of a BA(Hons) in Sound Technology there, it is a really good course. It is not specifically in sound design, although there is a module in it and a optional video production module in the third year, but it does provide a very well rounded curriculum.

They have really amazing facilities, and the lecturers know their stuff inside out.

[LIPA BA(hons) Sound Technology Undergraduate Course](http://www.lipa.ac.uk/content/Courses/UndergraduateCourses2/BAHonsSoundTechnology.aspx)

If you have any questions about it, or want any more details let me know.

Another really good one in the UK is the Tonnmeister course at Surrey -

[Surrey Tonmeister](http://www.surrey.ac.uk/soundrec/php/tonmeister.php)

Answer (score 2):

I received a well-rounded education in music and technology at [Berklee College of Music](http://www.berklee.edu/). If you cannot attend in the States, they also offer an [online curriculum](http://www.berkleemusic.com/?pid=3126).

Comment: im afraid, Berklee's online courses are offering very sketchy knowledge of design, based on one or several software products like Ableton or Reason...

Answer (score 2):

I did the MA in Sound Design for the Screen at Bournemouth University, however after just having a look they now offer a BA (Hons) in Soundtrack Production.

http://onlineservices.bournemouth.ac.uk/courses/course.aspx?course=644

The Media School was truly excellent. Great facilities and great staff. I really enjoyed the philosophy that theory informs practice and practice informs theory.

Ian

Answer (score 0):

Hi,

We offer this online Sound Design course -

http://www.pointblankonline.net/sound-design-course.php

It uses Native Instruments Kontakt and Reaktor.  There is a new course starting on the 5th and if you book before then you can get £50 off.  More details here -

http://www.pointblankonline.net/blog/get-phat-over-christmas-beef-up-your-production-this-winter/

Get in touch if you need any more info.